# mercurial wrong revision with hg update

Tags: mercurial

I have several branches

I'v done a :

```
hg clone -u branchtoto --rev 5308 ss://..... C:\myrepo
```

And then instead of 5308, i now have 4199 in my repo?
I would like revision 5308 of the branchtoto.

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over the `-u` and the `-r` (or `--rev`) options for `hg clone`. The `-r` option tells Mercurial up to which revision(s) to clone; the `-u` option tells Mercurial which revision to update to/check out. Also, as @planetmaker said, the short numerical IDs of another repository cannot be used in the context of the cloned one.

Answer (score 3):

The numericIDs are local to a specific repository only. A clone of a repository with branches will use different numericIDs.

The numericIDs are assigned sequentially to the revisions as they are added to the repository. If you make a narrow clone from a branchy repository, you will get less revisions than the remote repository has, thus the numericIDs of the revisions will nearly inevitably be different (unless you clone an old branch, and all revisions which you clone are of an older date than those which you do not clone, and no revisions must have been amended or obsoleted in that time either).

The hashes act as unique identifiers. Compare those and you'll find that they are identical accross different clones.